# How to simply navigate from One Component (Home Page ) to Another Component by clicking button using Router concept in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vuejs3

I know basics of html, css and js. I have just started learning Vue.js. There is a Home Page in my Vue JS Application which has two buttons. On Click of that button, navigation should happen. (New Component to be loaded). But, in the current code, on button click, navigation is not happening. Please Assist. Copying few file as seen below.

App.vue

```
<template>
  
<h3> Home  </h3> 
<button @click="goToCreate()"> Create Package  </button>
<br><br>
<button @click="goToEdit()"> Update Package  </button>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {

  },
   methods:{
   goToCreate(){
        this.$router.push('/createpackage'); 
    },
  goToEdit(){
        this.$router.push('/updatepackage'); 
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import App from './App.vue'
import CreatePackage from './components/CreatePackage.vue'
import SearchAndUpdatePackage from './components/SearchAndUpdatePackage.vue'
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes:[
        {
        path : '/createpackage',
        component:CreatePackage
    },{
        path : '/updatepackage',
        component:SearchAndUpdatePackage
    }

]
})

const app= createApp(App);
app.use(router).mount('#app')
```

config.js

```
let baseUrl = ''
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
   baseUrl = 'http://yourdomain.com/api/'
}
else {
   baseUrl = 'http://localhost:9000/'
}
export const apiHost = baseUrl
```

CreatePackage.vue

```
<template>
    
<div>
    <form name="createPackageForm" @submit="submitNewPackage" method="post">
        <input type="number" name="noOfPostpaid" placeholder="PostPaid" v-model="posts.noOfPostpaid"> 
        <br>  <br>   <br>
        <input type="number" name="noOfPrepaid"  placeholder="PrePaid" v-model="posts.noOfPrepaid"> 
          <br>  <br>  <br>
          <button>Submit</button>

</form>
</div>

</template>

<script>



    import { apiHost } from '../config'
    import axios from 'axios'
    
    export default {
        name:"CreatePackage",
        data(){
            return{
                posts: {
                    noOfPostpaid:null,
                   noOfPrepaid:null
                }
                
            }
        },
        methods:{
            submitNewPackage(e){
              
                console.warn(apiHost+'tdg/createpackage/'+this.posts.noOfPostpaid+'/'+this.posts.noOfPrepaid);
                e.preventDefault();
                  
                axios.post(apiHost+'tdg/createpackage/'+this.posts.noOfPostpaid+'/'+this.posts.noOfPrepaid,{
                  headers: {
                      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
                      }},null).then(
                  response => {
                console.log(response.data)}
                ).catch(e => {
                    console.log(e); 
                    })
                this.posts.noOfPostpaid='';
                this.posts.noOfPrepaid='';
    
             }
        }
    }
    
    </script>
```

SearchAndUpdatePackage.vue

```
<template>


<div>
    
        <input type="search" name="accountUUID" placeholder="Account UUID" v-model="posts.accountUUID"> 
        <br>  <br>   <br>
          <button  @click="searchAccountUUID">Search </button>

          <br>  <br>   <br>

 
 <textarea id="myTextArea" cols=100 rows=20 v-model="posts.responseJSON"></textarea>


   
</div>

</template>

<script>

import { apiHost } from '../config'


export default {
     name:"SearchAndUpdatePackage",
    data(){
        return{
            posts: {
                  accountUUID:null,
                 responseJSON:null
            },
           
            
        }
    },
      methods:{
        searchAccountUUID(e){
          
            const url=apiHost+'tdg/carbon/'+this.posts.accountUUID;
            console.log(url);
            e.preventDefault();
              
           fetch(url).then(response => response.json())
           .then(data=>this.posts.responseJSON=JSON.stringify(data,null,4))
             .catch(e => {
                console.log(e); 
                })
            
          console.log(this.posts.responseJSON);
      
         }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using [`router-view`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-view) anywhere?

Comment: try `goToEdit` not `goToEdit()`

Comment: @MichaelMano, I tried with goToEdit . Its not working.

Comment: @Daniel_Knights, I haven't used router-view. Please let me know the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Vue-Router, you need to use the [`router-view`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-view) component. When you navigate to a URL defined in your `routes` config, Vue-Router will match that URL and display the associated component.

It's common to place it in `App.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <h3> Home </h3> 
  <button @click="goToCreate()"> Create Package  </button>
  <br><br>
  <button @click="goToEdit()"> Update Package  </button>
  <router-view />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  methods: {
    goToCreate() {
      this.$router.push('/createpackage'); 
    },
    goToEdit() {
      this.$router.push('/updatepackage'); 
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

You might have an issue with it being a direct descendent of `<template>`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Once the button is clicked, components are rendering below the buttons only. I want components alone should get displayed in whole page. @Daniel_Knights

Comment: I am building a Multipage Application. So, It is just an UI having Home Page with number of Button clicks navigation to different Components to test backend APIs (Using Forms).  No Login feature as such. Just need to get achieve as commented above. Please Assist. Thanks

Comment: You'd have to either hide the buttons on navigation or have the buttons in their own component which is another route

Comment: These 2 ways doesn't fulfill requirement. I am wondering why it is looking tough for just load a new page on simple button click in Vue JS.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you're after

Comment: My Requirement is simple. The App.vue (Landing Page/Home Page) has two buttons. Onclick of the button should render the Component fully. Right now, your solution renders component below the two buttons. And, I don't want to disable buttons or have the button in their component (as you said , which is not my requirement.)  In normal html n js , it can be done with simple anchor tag. But, here, I am not sure why it is looking difficult to render component fully onclick of button.  Let me know the exact code changes for my requirement. Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't you want the buttons in their own component? If you want a full-page change, the two choices I suggested above are your only options.

Comment: Can u please give the code changes. Let me execute and see.